# remove backslash from json string

Tags: php

I get bellow json string from a server response:

```
"\"[\n      {\n        \"id\": \"1\",\n        \"mid\": \"1\",\n        \"num\": \"1\",\n        \"type\": \"wgp\",\n        \"time_changed\": \"time\",\n        \"username\": \"aaa\"\n      }\n    ]\""
```

I need to reformat it to this:

```
"{ { "id": "1", "mid": "1", "num": "1", "type": "wgp", "time_changed": "time", "username": "aaa" } }
```

here is my attempt

```
    $str = substr($str, 2);
    $str = "{".$str;
    $str = substr($str,0, strlen($str) - 3);
    $str = $str . " }";
    $str = trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $str));
```

it gives me

```
"{ { \"id\": \"1\", \"mid\": \"1\", \"num\": \"1\", \"plating_type\": \"wgp\", \"time_changed\": \"time\", \"username\": \"09122099111\" } }"
```

I could not remove backslashes I tried

```
$str= preg_replace('/\\\"/', '', $str); 
$str = str_replace('\\', '', $str);
stripslashes ()
```

but none of them worked

Comment: `$str = str_replace('\\', '', $str);` this is working for me with your example

Comment: Why don't you use `json_decode()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following way to achieve what you need,

```
$jsonString = '\"[\n      {\n        \"id\": \"1\",\n        \"mid\": \"1\",\n        \"num\": \"1\",\n        \"type\": \"wgp\",\n        \"time_changed\": \"time\",\n        \"username\": \"aaa\"\n      }\n    ]\"';

$jsonString = str_replace('\\n', '', $jsonString); // First remove the new line characters in the json string

$jsonString = str_replace('\\', '', $jsonString); // Replace backslash with empty string

echo preg_replace('!\s+!', ' ', $jsonString); // Replace multiple spaces with one
```

So the output is,

> "[ { "id": "1", "mid": "1", "num": "1", "type": "wgp", "time_changed":
>   "time", "username": "aaa" } ]"

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be receiving that string wrapped in `\"\"`, else it would be invalid json and no sane API would produce it. (if that is, unfortunately, the case, then contact the author or strip the first 2 chars and last two chars).

Then that is perfectly valid JSON, so you can just pass it to json_decode, then re-encode it again, no stripping whitespace required.

```
<?php
$json = "[\n      {\n        \"id\": \"1\",\n        \"mid\": \"1\",\n        \"num\": \"1\",\n        \"type\": \"wgp\",\n        \"time_changed\": \"time\",\n        \"username\": \"aaa\"\n      }\n    ]";

echo json_encode(json_decode($json));
```

Which will produce your desired result:

`[{"id":"1","mid":"1","num":"1","type":"wgp","time_changed":"time","username":"aaa"}]`

https://3v4l.org/ul3M4